Can`t install ibis-anthy
I try to install anthy for Japan. I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Get this:
montes@montes-PT$ sudo apt install ibus-anthy
Reading package lists... Done
Building a dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done         
Package ibus-anthy is not available, but is listed in another dependency list
package. This could mean that the package is missing, outdated, or
available from sources not mentioned in sources.list

E: No installation candidate found for package "ibus-anthy"

What i can do with this ?
